# Test Adobe AIR mobile apps on iOS without Dev license

Tags: ios, debugging, code-signing, ios-provisioning

I am not quite sure if this question is suitable for stackoverflow but it doesn't fit on any other network that I know.

I am developing a mobile application in Adobe AIR (Flash builder) that is meant to be run on iOS. I have not yet signed up for Apple Developer program (99$/year) and therefore don't have an iOS developer certificate to build and sign my code with. Is there a way to run/debug my applications on actual device without the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be ways to do so on a jailbroken device, but on a non-jailbroken device you always need a valid certificate to install an app (also for debugging).

Comment: <offtopic> Is it legal to ask the same question with regards to jailbroken devices here? </offtopic>

Comment: Yes, it's fine ask about this here, but this question has already been asked and answered here a few times :-) Try using the search.